# Can I split a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

The instructions for a bounty rewarding exemplary existing answers states:

> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

However, it doesn't look like I can split the bounty.  It appears that I can only award it to one question.  I was also surprised that I had no option but a 500 point option.  This wouldn't be a big deal if I can split the bounty (as I expected I could do).  It's a bigger deal if I cannot.

Can I split the bounty?  If not, can we change the text for this particular bounty to read:

> One of the answers is exemplary and worth of an additional bounty.

and allow me to choose a bounty size other than 500 points?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), there can be only one bounty winner or none at all. But it is possible to award several bounties consecutively. The value of each new bounty must be at least twice as big as the one before.

Also, the minimum value for the bounty is 50 points and 500 is the maximum.
If 500 is the only option, it probably means that the question already awarded another bounty and 500 is now the minimum. I guess that's what the quote means by "additional bounty".

Comment: This is, indeed, the case.  I offered a 250pt bounty initially to draw interest in the question.  There are two answers beyond the awardee deserving of special consideration.  My original thought was, since the text reads "one or more," that I'd accept the 500pt option and split it between the two.  I'm not happy with the "twice the last one" rule.  I can only imagine that it's to keep people from offering a ton of 50pt bounties, but it's petty, ultimately minimizing the use of the bounty system.  But that's another question.

Comment: Oh, it was *your* bounty before.  If the question had had a bounty from somebody else, then that shouldn't affect a new bounty.  I'm not a fan of the "must keep increasing" rule either.  Or, at least, it'd be nice if sites could opt out; I assume it exists because it's been abused somewhere, but that doesn't mean it was (or would be) abused here.  Besides, moderators can refund bounties and send Stern Messages to people who abuse the site.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Abusing this system seems like an old issue and not possible anymore. Every points put as a bounty would be earned back at the end with no additional gains. It might become an abuse if someone use this as a cheap way to avoid the daily rep cap since bounties are not affected by the cap.

Comment: @MonicaCellio So if someone else offered a bounty it could be for any amount? I assume another bounty can't be offered until the current one is finished though.